# Cassandra giving time out exception after some inserts

Tags: exception, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.0.6 version... I have around ~1million JSON Objects of 5KB each to be inserted to the cassandra. As the inserts goes on, the memory consumption of cassandra also goes up until it gets stable to certain point.. After some inserts(around 2-3 lkhs) the ruby client gives me "`recv_batch_mutate': CassandraThrift::TimedOutException" exception.

I have also tried inserting 1KB sized JSON Objects more than a million times. This doesnt give any exception. Also in this experiment I plotted a graph between time taken by 50000 inserts vs number of 50000 inserts. I could find that there is a sharp rise in time taken to inserts after some iterations and suddenly that falls down. This could be due to Garbage collection done by JVM. But the same doesnt happen while inserting 5KB of data for a million times.

What may be the problem?? Some of the configuration options which I am using:-
System:-

- 8GB with 4-core ..

Cassandra configuration:-
 - concurrent_writes: 64

- memtable_flush_writers: 4
- memtable_flush_queue_size: 8
- rpc_server_type: sync
- thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 30
- in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64
- multithreaded_compaction: true

Do I need to do any changes in configuration. Is it related to JVM heap space or due to Garbage collection ??

Comment: Are you doing a batch insert? If so what is your batch size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the rpc timeout to a larger value in cassandra config file, look for **rpc_timeout_in_ms** . But you should really look into your ruby client on the connection part.

```
# Time to wait for a reply from other nodes before failing the command
rpc_timeout_in_ms: 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have a use-case where I have to do over 2 millions of reads and writes every day.. If I increase the rpc_timeout_in_ms, wont it affect the throughput.. Moreover I am using a single noded cluster.. Will it perform well with multi node cluster??

Comment: probably you should really look into your ruby client code. i'm not well verse in ruby but we have multi nodes in our environment, pumping million of records into cluster using hector, and in the same time, reading from cassandra node and it's working fine. Maybe you should file a question with your ruby client code and the guru can comment more on it. It is very difficult to guess here and we are just scratching the surface.